# Which Matlab native classes are sealed?

Tags: matlab, oop

The `Sealed` attribute when applied to a Matlab class prevents it from being subclasses, per http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-attributes.html

I am interested to find out which of the native Matlab classes (in R2015b) are sealed.

Comment: [Built-In Types You Cannot Subclass](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/subclassing-matlab-built-in-classes.html#btnoj12).

Comment: That said, to me, it is odd (i.e., inconsistent) that methods can be added to `cell` and not `table` per your other question.

Comment: thanks, copying the relevant sections of the linked page + attributing it will constitute an answer for me. For my other question, you seem to have thought of the same thing as I did: it seems clear now that whether you can add methods or not does not depend on whether the class is sealed.